# Asking "Who is this?" on the telephone

Tags: conversation, existentials

A telephone call might start like this

> **ring**  **ring**
>   **Alice:** Hello, who is this?
>   **Bob:** Hey, Bob here. Is this Alice?
>   **Alice:** Yes, indeed.

Now in school I learned to use *this* for objects in my close range and *that* for objects further away.

Is there a reason why we use "who is this" instead of "who are you"? I realize it sounds more polite this way, but can't help to feel grammatically awkward.

Comment: "Who is this?" is just an idiomatic way to ask, "Who is on the other end of this phone conversation?" (or, much more stiltedly, "With whom am I speaking?") Interesting how we say "Who's this?" on the telephone, but "Who is it?" (or, "Who's there?") at the doorway.

Comment: @J.R. And that "interesting" part motivated my question :)

Comment: Imagine that you were blindfolded. Then someone touched your shoulder and said *"Be still."* Which question would you ask: *"Who is this?"* or *"Who is that?"*

Comment: I regard “Who is this?” as practically equivalent to “Who am I?”, and suggest saying  “Who's calling, please?” instead.

Comment: The whole thing sounds awkward. I haven't heard anyone who would start a telephone call like that.

Comment: I would like to add that _this_ telephone exchange sounds strange to me as well. Usually, the person answering the phone says, simply, "Hello..." or might identify herself, saying, "Hello; (this is) Alice speaking." Then the caller identifies himself, and the conversation can go on. It is not often that someone doesn't identify himself, but when he doesn't, it's perfectly OK to say, "Who is this?" or, more politely, "Who am I speaking to?" (it should be whom, but this is ok in everyday speech), or, "May I ask who's calling?"

Comment: @Susan, If you're going to use *whom* you might also want to change the word order: "To whom am I speaking?". For learners, if you are learning American English, you may ignore *whom* altogether, and just use *who*.

Comment: I would recommend being more polite and saying something like "May I ask who's calling?", but only on grounds of politeness, not because I think anyone would misunderstand "Who is this?"  (Which, to be honest, I doubt.)

Answer (score 7):

It's true that *this* and *that* are relative to distance. For phone conversations, the distance is metaphorical. In the case of phone conversations, "this" is who you are talking to. If you heard someone in the background talking (i.e. a voice in the distance on the other side of the line) you could say "Who's that?"

Comment: This answer explains nicely, why it's "this" instead of "that". But If I met a person face to face, unsure about their identity, I would never ask them "Who is this?". Why is it common on the phone? (feel free to expand your answer :))